# Vector as a part of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, scalar-fields

I need to calculate directional derivative for such scalar field:

$$u=y\ln(l+x^2)-\arctan z\;\text{ where }\;\vec \ell=2\vec i-3\vec j-2\vec k, \;\text{ and }\;M(0,1,1).$$

The question is - what should I do with the $\ell$ in the $u(x,y,z)$? Just put in $l=2-3-2=-3$?

Comment: Probably $l$ (without arrow) means the norm of the vector $\vec l$ (with arrow). Hence $l=\sqrt{2^2+(-3)^2+(-2)^2}=\sqrt{17}$.

Comment: I would expect then symbol $|l|$ because this is how in all other scalar field directional derivative examples length of vector $\vec l$ is designated here in Latvia.

Comment: Yes. That symbol is much more common, or $\|\vec l\|$.  But it's the unuique possibility for me...

Comment: That's true. Just found out that $\vec l = \mathbf l$ and $|\mathbf l| = |\vec l| = l$